# Apache Rewrite Whirlwind

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have inherited an environment where they used a re-write rule to redirect 1400+ clients with HTTPD/Apache. I am looking to add a subdomain for development (so a multi level subdomain) and I am getting "Passed 10 internal redirects" I am hoping I can get a little assist.

What They Have Currently that works for a single level subdomain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin support@domain.com
        ServerName client.domain.com
        ServerAlias *.domain.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/hosted/%1.0.domain.com"
        Options FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On
        CustomLog journald vhost
        ErrorLog journald

        <Location /app>
                Require all denied
        </Location>

        # Redirect content that needs to be secure
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NE,L]
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName client.domain.com:443
        ServerAlias *.domain.com
        #DataDog Variables
        SetEnv DD_SERVICE 'apache_pre-log'
        SetEnv DD_ENV 'all-encompassing'
        SetEnv DD_VERSION '1'
        SetEnv DD_TRACE_SAMPLE_RATE '1'
        
        
        # DocumentRoot "/var/www/hosted/www.easypeasyticketing.com"
        #Doc Root
        VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/hosted/%-3+.0.domain.com"

        # Use separate log files for the SSL virtual host; note that LogLevel
        # is not inherited from httpd.conf.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog logs/ssl_access_log.log vhost
        ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log.log
        CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
                  "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard.domain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/wildcard.domain.com.key
        # Can be same as SSLCertificateFile
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard.domain.com.crt

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        Options FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On

        # Ref: https://serverfault.com/a/644116
        Alias /_error/ /var/www/errors/
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond /var/www/hosted/%1.domain.com/ !-d
        RewriteRule ^ /_error/no_box_office.php [PT,L]

        <Directory "/var/www/hosted">
                Require all granted
#               DirectoryIndex index.php
#               FallbackResource /index.php
                RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ /login [R=301,NE,L]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
        </Directory>

        <Location /app>
                Require all denied
        </Location>

        <LocationMatch "/\.git.*">
                Require all denied
        </LocationMatch>

        <Location /uploads>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                php_admin_value engine off
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

My Modifications

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin support@domain.com
        ServerName client.dev.domain.com
        ServerAlias *.dev.domain.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/hosted/%1.0.domain.com"
        Options FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On
        CustomLog journald vhost
        ErrorLog journald

        <Location /app>
                Require all denied
        </Location>

        # Redirect content that needs to be secure
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NE,L]
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName client.dev\domain.com:443
        ServerAlias *.dev.domain.com
        #DataDog Variables
        SetEnv DD_SERVICE 'apache_pre-log'
        SetEnv DD_ENV 'all-encompassing'
        SetEnv DD_VERSION '1'
        SetEnv DD_TRACE_SAMPLE_RATE '1'
        
        
        #Doc Root
        VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/hosted/%-3+.0.dev.domain.com"

        # Use separate log files for the SSL virtual host; note that LogLevel
        # is not inherited from httpd.conf.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog logs/ssl_access_log.log vhost
        ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log.log
        CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
                  "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard.domain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/wildcard.domain.com.key
        # Can be same as SSLCertificateFile
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard.domain.com.crt

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        Options FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On

        # Ref: https://serverfault.com/a/644116
        Alias /_error/ /var/www/errors/
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.dev\.domain\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteCond /var/www/hosted/%1.dev.domain.com/ !-d
        RewriteRule ^ /_error/no_box_office.php [PT,L]

        <Directory "/var/www/hosted">
                Require all granted
#               DirectoryIndex index.php
#               FallbackResource /index.php
                RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ /login [R=301,NE,L]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
        </Directory>

        <Location /app>
                Require all denied
        </Location>

        <LocationMatch "/\.git.*">
                Require all denied
        </LocationMatch>

        <Location /uploads>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                php_admin_value engine off
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The `ServerName` in the VirtualHost *:443 has some error.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, just in case someone else has a multilevel subdomain issue just like I had,

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/hosted/%-3+.0.dev.domain.com"
```

needed to be changed to reflect the proper placement on the Sub-Sub Domain

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/hosted/%-4+.0.dev.domain.com"
```

the `%-#` is the placement of the "cursor" 1 being ".COM" 2 Being "Domain" 3 being "subdomain" 4 being "sub sub domain"